# Aggregating Individual District Assignments to Census Block

Tags: spatial-statistics, aggregation, apportion

Working on a solution that may work but figured I'd ask the community to see if there's a smarter way to get this task done.

I have a voter registration file with district assignments for each voter. I have a census block assignment for each voter linked on their unique identifier. 95% of those census block assignments are accurate.

Is there an easy way to "build up" to the census block to confirm accuracy? For instance, if I know voter x lives in County A, Precinct 3, and Legislative District Y---how can I programatically ensure that that voters assigned census block falls into the list of possibilities for that combination of districts?

Using this process, I could potentially narrow down the list of possible assignments to 3-5 blocks for the 5% of voters I'm not confident have correct assignments and begin cleaning my data set up better.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I prefer QGIS and PostGIS but have Arc handy.

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question asked per question, and if you are asking the same thing for each of potentially three GIS products then this will be too broad for our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend that you decide which one you are most likely to try using first and then ask about just that.  You can always ask about the others separately, if you need to.